# Восстановить удаленный git репозиторий по локальному

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

Так получилось что в удаленном репозитории git создал по ошибке новый репозиторий и после этого не все коммиты просматриваются (исчезли последние). У меня есть локальный репозиторий, как мне его запушить обратно в удаленный, чтобы восстановить последний?
Обязательно удалять удаленный или на него накатить можно? Локальный содержит несколько веток, как можно запушить их все сразу?

Comment: это два репо пересекаются по коммитам?  то есть, есть ли общие sha коммитов там и там?

Comment: Что означает первое предложение?